# Retrieving JSON from HttpResponse from Django view

Tags: python, json, django

So in a view for one of my Django apps, the method returns a HttpResponse object.

```
json_str = json.dumps(json_dict)
return HttpResponse(json_str, content_type="application/json")
```

In my test module for the app (tests.py), I have simulated a GET request

```
def setUp(self):
    c = Client()
    response = c.get('/url/to/view/')
```

From what I read in the Django testing documentation, response will be a Response object, which is similar but not exactly the same as a HttpResponse object. So how do I retrieve the json string from response?

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look at [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) which is a subclass of HTTPResponse.

From the testing client you can retrieve the actual response string with the attribute content:

```
>>> from django.test import Client
>>> c = Client()
>>> response = c.post('/login/', {'username': 'john', 'password': 'smith'})
>>> response.status_code
200
>>> response = c.get('/customer/details/')
>>> response.content
'<!DOCTYPE html...'
```

If the response happens to contain json the string will contain the JSON.

The testing tools also include helpful tools for working with JSON like [assertJSONEqual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertJSONEqual).

If you want to convert the response string to actual python dictionaries, you can do this with

```
import json

response = json.loads(c.get('/myjsonview/').content)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve response json like this:

```
import json

response = json.loads(c.get('/url/to/view/').content)
```